# Spring 3 testing

Tags: spring, junit

I am new to unit testing.  I've been looking for a comprehensive tutorial on testing in the Spring 3 framework without much luck.  Anybody have good resources?

Thanks, Eric

Comment: We generally don't allow "*gimme links*" questions. However have a look at [official documentation on testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html), pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, Spring support for testing is usefull most of all when you are writing integration tests. And as Tomasz noted there is a good description of testing functionality in official doc.

If you need to write unit tests I recomend you to use mocking framework like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). They have a good documentation how to use their framework. And this framework is really easy to learn.

Also there is a good discussion about [Unit vs Integration testing in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281758/unit-tests-vs-integration-tests-with-spring).