# Integration tests with JUnit and web MVC

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I am working on a Spring MVC application.

Unit tests are already writen (nice 85% code coverage and lots of assertions :)

Now I need to write integration tests. I already have a look at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281758/unit-tests-vs-integration-tests-with-spring) still I do have some questions

- Right now I am using a standard maven structure with main and test directories, do you recommend to create another directory called integration-tests and write the unit tests there? If so, why?
- Another alternative would be to write the integration tests in the "tests" directory, mixing unit and integration tests, and then using maven to run one or the other (maybe using different file suffixes depending on the test type)
- In any case, the way I am planning to run the integration tests is essentially to (almost) reuse the unit tests of the controllers WITHOUT injecting mocks, that means that my current stack (Controller-Service-DAO) will contain no mocks (of course, in the unit tests, it does), by removing the mocks I will access to the real resources (Database and so), is this a good approach?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, the project has not JSP or any HTML-related views, output is XML which can be easily validated with XSDs

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have used JUNIT to create your unit tests to achieve the impressive 85% code coverage. Please notice that JUNIT is designed for unit testing only (thus the name JUNIT). Unit testing is done while the code is running in the development environment.

Integration testing can only be performed once the target code has been deployed in the target integration environment.

You have mentioned that you application isn't a web application. Is it SOAP/Rest Web Service? If so, you can use  Soap UI [http://www.soapui.org/], to create and save automated regression/integration tests.

Comment: The application is a webservice but it does not uses SOAP.